# Как расположить after элемент за родительским элементом?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы `after` элемент был перекрыт родительским? `z-index` не помогает.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  z-index: 10;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: добавь картинку, чтобы было понятно какой конечный результат ожидается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто убери `z-index` у родителя.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  z-index: 10;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: -25%;
  right: -25%;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```